# 'NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' for nil:NilClass' when functional testing with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, functional-testing

This is not a question, it a solution that I found.

I am developing an application with Ruby on Rails 4.1 that displays text in Spanish, English and Japanese.

When I started the Functional Testing, I keep getting the following error:

**NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' for nil:NilClass**

Surffing I saw several posts with the same error, but none work for me.

This is the code original code:

*application_controller.rb*:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    navegador = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    ruta = params[:locale] || nil
    unless ruta.blank?
      I18n.locale = ruta if IDIOMAS.flatten.include? ruta
    else
      I18n.locale = navegador if IDIOMAS.flatten.include? navegador
    end
  end

  private

  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
  end

  def ajusta_pagina_filtro
    if defined? params[:post][:filtrar_por]
      buscar = params[:post][:filtrar_por]
    else
      buscar = ''
    end
    page = params[:pagina] || 1
    [page, buscar]
  end

end
```

So this is the code for */test/controllers/homes_controller_test.rb* at:

```
require 'test_helper'

class HomesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

So, when I 'rake test', I got:

```
  1) Error:
HomesControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:22:in `extract_locale_from_accept_language_header'
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `set_locale'
    test/controllers/homes_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:HomesControllerTest>'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5):

The following solutions will also work without a begin rescue block

```
def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
   accept_language = (request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] || 'es').scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
end
```

Or

```
def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  return 'es' unless request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
  request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
end
```

Comment: That is right. I had not thought about it. Thanks engineersmnky

Answer (score 1):

The problem whas that at *application_controller.rb*, the method *extract_locale_from_accept_language_header* is failling. It is not getting the lananguage header from the *request*.

So I change it to:

```
  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    begin
      request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
    rescue
      'es'
    end
  end
```

I hope you find this usefull.